# How to show GIF using Glade

Tags: python, gtk, glade

is there any way how to show animated .gif file in my program using just Glade? Means I don't want to edit my code-behind.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know, you can't. You need to use a gtk image widget in your glade file, later use the following apis in your python code:

[gtk.gdk.PixbufAnimation](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gdkpixbufanimation.html)
[gtk.Image.set_from_animation](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkimage.html#method-gtkimage--set-from-animation) 
The first one creates the animation object from a file, the later pass the object animation to your gtk.Image